# SSH -f in a script - Getting a signal when the command is executed

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ssh

So, here I am : I'm writing a script in Python that does the following :

- Launches a command to start a logging process (bash script) on the server via SSH
- Uses ab to benchmark the server from the client
- Recovers the log file generated on the server with scp
- Generates a graph with matplotlib with the data on the client

I will enclose both scripts at the end, but I doubt they are of any use for that question.

So as not to wait for the logging script launched via SSH to end to continue the python script, I used -f with SSH to send it in the background.
The python script does continue, but I find myself having a problem related to the time of the logging process and benchmarking which may greatly vary depending on the client's network access and processing power.

I wish to launch the logging command on the server in a way that allows myself to keep going with the python script on the client to perform the benchmarking, but I also don't want to start the plotting client side before the logging is finished server side. Now I cannot do that by calculating an approximate sleep, because it will vary depending on the client and connection.

So I would like to launch the retrieval of the logging file and plotting only when the logging script has exited on the client, which would be the successful execution and exiting of the SSH command.

How do I keep track of the SSH command status within python to only start that part of the script when the SSH command (which is in the background) has exited ?

I would like to avoid using threading, as it is not very adapted to a script. I'm of course open to any better suggestion I haven't though of.

**Logging file, server side**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#perf_measurement.sh

# logs the load average every n seconds for a y period of time in a csv file

# interval, in seconds, for the load measure
INTERVAL=1
# amount of measures
MEASURES=$1
# path of the logging file
LOGFILE_EXT=".csv"
LOGFILE="$2""$LOGFILE_EXT"
# separator for the csv file
SEPARATOR=","
# load average file
LOADFILE="/proc/loadavg"
# timestamp at start of measure/script
INIT_TIMESTAMP=`date +%s`

# clearing logfile
if [ -e $LOGFILE ]; then
  rm $LOGFILE
fi

# function to get one of the load average values from LOADFILE
loadpm () {
  cat $LOADFILE | cut -d' ' -f$1
}
# function generation a timestamp starting from the start of the script, in seconds
timestamp () {
  echo $(expr $(date +%s) - $INIT_TIMESTAMP)
}

for (( i=0; i<$MEASURES; i++ )) ; do
  echo $(timestamp)$SEPARATOR$(loadpm 1) >> $LOGFILE
  sleep $INTERVAL
done


exit 0
```

**Python script, client side**
    #!/usr/bin/python
    #benchmark.py

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import time

SERVER = "edited"
SERVER_USER = "ubuntu"
SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT_PATH = "/var/www/html"
SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT = "perf_measurement.sh"
REQUESTS = 1000000 # high because time limitation is used instead of number of requests to facilitate logging

CONCURRENCY = input("Input concurrency for test : ")
MEASURE_TIME = input("Input time of the test (in seconds) : ")
FILE = input("Input name of file/repo for test (without the extension) : ")
TEST_NAME = input("Input a name for the test (no space) : ")
FILENAME= f"{TEST_NAME}_conc_{CONCURRENCY}"
GRAPH_FILE = f"{FILENAME}.png"
LOG_FILE = f"{FILENAME}.csv"

FILE_PATH = f"/{FILE}"
TEST_TIME = int(int(MEASURE_TIME) - int(MEASURE_TIME) / 4)
SLEEP_TIME = int(int(MEASURE_TIME) / 8)


SSH_COMMAND = f"ssh -f {SERVER_USER}@{SERVER} 'cd {SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT_PATH}&&./"\
                f"{SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT} {MEASURE_TIME} {FILENAME}'"
AB_COMMAND = f"ab -c {CONCURRENCY} -t {TEST_TIME} -n {REQUESTS} {SERVER}{FILE_PATH}"
SCP_COMMAND = f"scp {SERVER_USER}@{SERVER}:{SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT_PATH}/{LOG_FILE} ."

print(SSH_COMMAND)

print("\nStarting the logging server side...\n")
os.system(SSH_COMMAND)

print(f"\nSleeping {SLEEP_TIME} seconds to visualize load gain...\n")
time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

print("\nStarting benchmark...\n")
os.system(AB_COMMAND)

print("\nRecovering log file from server...\n")
os.system(SCP_COMMAND)


print("\nGenerating graph...\n")
# declaring list for coordinates of the graph
x_coord = []
y_coord = []

# opening log file
with open(LOG_FILE, "r") as csvfile:

    # reading csv logfile
    logfile = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # iterating through logfile
    for row in logfile:
        # storing coordinates in list
        x_coord.append(int(row[0]))
        y_coord.append(float(row[1]))


# generation graph
plt.plot(x_coord, y_coord)
plt.ylabel('Load average (from /proc/loadavg)')
plt.xlabel('Time')

# exporting graph to png
plt.savefig(GRAPH_FILE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the rather unique nature of this script, it seems like a good use-case for [`subprocess.Popen(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Rather than sending your SSH command to the background, you can use Popen to launch it with a handle to the process. Then you can proceed to conduct whatever tests you need to perform on your side and return to that process handle before you `scp` the results. This should work because the `ssh` command, when provided a set of commands at the end of its method call, sends the command(s) instead of opening an interactive login shell, and then returns the output to the client machine. Once the remote command finishes, `ssh` closes the connection and exits its own process. Therefore, the following should work:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

# ... your other imports and code...

_PROC_TIMEOUT_SEC = 5
SSH_COMMAND = (
                f"ssh {SERVER_USER}@{SERVER} 'cd {SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT_PATH}&&./"
                f"{SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT} {MEASURE_TIME} {FILENAME}'"
              )
AB_COMMAND = f"ab -c {CONCURRENCY} -t {TEST_TIME} -n {REQUESTS} {SERVER}{FILE_PATH}"
SCP_COMMAND = f"scp {SERVER_USER}@{SERVER}:{SERVER_PERF_MEASUREMENT_SCRIPT_PATH}/{LOG_FILE} ."

print("\nStarting the logging server side...\n")
portioned_ssh_command = shlex.split(SSH_COMMAND)
ssh_proc = subprocess.Popen(portioned_ssh_command)

# Still perform your testing as you had planned...
# Not sure if you need to sleep here, but I'll leave that up to you.
print(f"\nSleeping {SLEEP_TIME} seconds to visualize load gain...\n")
time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
print("\nStarting benchmark...\n")
os.system(AB_COMMAND)

# Wait for SSH process to finish before attempting to scp log file.
ssh_return_code = None
while(ssh_return_code is None):
    try:
        ssh_return_code = ssh_proc.wait(_PROC_TIMEOUT_SEC)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        pass

print(f"Info: SSH completed with exitcode {ssh_proc.returncode}")

# Now that SSH 
print("\nRecovering log file from server...\n")
os.system(SCP_COMMAND)

# ... The rest of your code...
```

**Note**: I have not tested the code above, but I am highly confident that will do what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's quite a good way to go and works much better like that, and is a module I'll remember.

With 3.7, I had to slight issues (typos) with the script : The class name is Popen, giving ssh_proc = subprocess.Popen(portioned_ssh_command). Also, the error need to have its module specified : except subprocess.TimeoutExpired: .

Comment: @Naboochodonosor, glad to help, and thank you for pointing out those issues. I hadn't tried running it, but I will modify my answer with your feedback!